# Forcing a logoff from a Joomla admin session

Tags: ajax, session, joomla, timeout, logoff

In Joomla! 3.6, we're trying to force a user to the login screen from the admin section if their session has expired, but *without* any user input. By default, Joomla! will send people to the login screen if they attempt to load a page after their session has expired. This is something we want automated so if someone walks away and forgets to lock their system, the current page(s) can't be accessed if the session times out.

My initial attempt around this was to run a timed JS loop in administrator\index.php and have it make an AJAX call to an external PHP file that could query the session table. However, including jQuery at such a high level causes many other references to break due to it being included more than once. Due to how the default redirect action works, all this really needs to do is force a page refresh.

Is there a better way or location to do this without breaking existing code?

Answer (score 0):

This required two things to fix.

1) Add

`// jQuery needed by template.js
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');`

2) Change $.ajax to jQuery.ajax